# Convert textarea into pagedown editor loaded dynamically using ajax (from server side)

Tags: javascript, pagedown

I got a file like server.php which contains a simple textarea like

```
 <textarea id="wmd-input" rows="10" cols="60" style="margin-top: 5px"></textarea>
```

I tried to load this server.php content dynamically in my index.htm file using ajax

it loaded perfectly in the desired #id (container) but the problem is that the textarea which loaded dynamically was not converted into pagedown markdown editor

I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null
```

Updated:

[Hope this will help you to understand](http://jsfiddle.net/3f25p0r2/)

Comment: Why are you trying to put the textarea into a container dynamically? Why not putting only the content of the textarea into the textarea (which will be your container)?

Comment: Because I want to get the content from user through that textarea

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide more code?

Comment: I provided a link above. The code is still not complete ... but i just want that pagedown markdown editor in place of that textarea

Comment: You create your markdown editor before printing the results of your Ajax call. You need to put `(function () { var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter(); var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1); editor1.run(); })();` at the end of the Ajax `complete` function.

Comment: thanks @pmrotule it works but you know i still getting that error :
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null in Markdown.Sanitizer.js:324`
how i gonna get rid of this ... not compulsory but i dont want it there :D